# JavaScript Regular expression, characters can't be all the same

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that only allows numbers from 0-9, and letters from a-z or A-Z. No max length. Digits can't be all the same. For example,

Not allowed:
000000
11111111
aaaaaaaaa
BBBBB

Allowed:
00000001
11111111112
AAAAAAAAAAAAAB

I've tried `/^(?!(.)\1{5})[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/` but looks like it only checks if the first 5 letter repeats.

Is there a way to check the pattern without giving a fixed length?

Comment: Do you *have* to use regex or are you open to more typical JS solutions?

Comment: Why not use `^(.)(\1)*$` and negate the result? This matches strings that consist of only one character.

Comment: "Not equal to" rule is `^(?!B$).*`. So, you need `$`,  `/^(?!(.)\1{5}$)[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/`. Or, also try `/^(?!(.)\1{5}(?!\1))[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Doesn't `^` match the beginning of the line, though (at least in JavaScript regex)?

Comment: `^` matches the start of string here.